# Search Function is not returning the correct search when text is keyed in Search input

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, keyboard, jquery-events

***Functionality:***

When user clicks on Search Input box, a jQuery keyboard will be displayed. User then clicks on the characters shown on the jQuery keyboard to type out the item name that is being searched. If there are matches, the image of the item will be displayed, else nothing will be shown.

***What has been done:***

I have created the following:

1. an Input tag for the Search box and when user clicks on the input box,the jQuery keyboard will be displayed.
2. I have created a function that every input of the key from the jQuery keyboard, it will perform `keyup` function to do a check on the input character with the file name of the item to see if there are a match.
   If match, display the image of the item, else, nothing is shown.

***Code:***

```js
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/Pxyz/img/xyz.jpg.png", "lib/img/xyz/img/xyz.jpasdfg.png", "lib/img/xyz/img/xyz.jpgasdf.png", "lib/img/xyz/img/xyz.jpqweg.png"];

$("#SearchField").keyup(function() {
  var userInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var showImages = 0;

  console.log("keyup here");

  $("#list img").each(function() {

    $this = $(this),
      imageName = $this.attr('src').split('/'); // Split src by '/'

    // Get last part (filename)
    imageName = imageName.pop();

    // Remove extension
    imageName = imageName.split('.')[0];

    // Show images with matching filename
    //$this.toggle(imageName.indexOf(userInput) >= 0);

    //if we can show an image, increment showImages
    if (imageName.indexOf(userInput) >= 0) {
      $this.toggle(imageName.indexOf(userInput));
      showImages++;
    }
  });
  //if this stays at 0 we have shown no images, display error message
  if (!showImages) {
    //append text to a div to show error message
    $("#Brand_wrong").fadeIn();
  }
});


$("#SearchField").click(function() {

  document.getElementById("ClickSoundAudio").play();
  $("#SearchField").val("");
  $("#Brand_wrong").hide();

  //Disable Button click  
  $("#BrandPageBackButton").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#showAll").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#showFnB").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#showBeauty").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#showFashion").prop("disabled", true);

  //Keyboard Script
  //To remove 'click' event before adding new click 'event' everytime after page is loaded: allow keyboard character event to be run only once only when page is loaded
  $('#SearchKeyBoard').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {
      $('#Search_keyboard li').off('click').on('click', function() {
        console.log("click");
        idleTime = 0;

        var $this = $(this),
          character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable
        console.log(character);
        // Shift keys
        if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
          $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
          $('.symbol span').toggle();

          shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
          capslock = false;
          return false;
        }

        // Caps lock
        if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
          $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
          capslock = true;
          return false;
        }

        // Delete
        if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
          var html = $write.val();

          $write.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
          return false;
        }

        // Clear
        if ($this.hasClass('clear')) {
          var html = $write.val();

          $write.val("");
          return false;
        }

        // Special characters
        if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
        if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
        if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
        if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

        // Uppercase letter
        if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

        // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
        if (shift === true) {
          $('.symbol span').toggle();
          if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

          shift = false;
        }
        // Add the character and trigger keyup event manually when keypad is clicked
        //$write.val($write.val() + character).trigger('keyup');

        var inputValue = $write.val();
        textBefore = inputValue.substring(0, cursorPos);
        textAfter = inputValue.substring(cursorPos, inputValue.length);

        $write.val(textBefore + character + textAfter).trigger('keyup');
        cursorPos += character.length;
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```css
/* Keyboard CSS*/

.keyboard {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.keyboard li {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2 2 2 2;
  width: 65px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #a497b4;
  border: 1px solid #5e5767;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.capslock,
.tab,
.left-shift {
  clear: left;
}
.keyboard .tab,
.keyboard .delete {
  width: 165px;
}
.keyboard .capslock {
  width: 101px;
}
.keyboard .return {
  width: 101px;
}
.keyboard .left-shift {
  width: 165px;
}
.keyboard .right-shift {
  width: 165px;
}
.lastitem {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.keyboard .space {
  clear: left;
  width: 685px;
}
.on {
  display: none;
}
.keyboard li:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
Search {
  position: absolute;
  width: 330px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 1620px;
  left: 410px;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="SearchField" style="position:absolute; top:390px; left:220px; height:50px; width:600px; outline: 0; border: 0; font-size:25px; font-family:'CenturyGothic'; background: transparent; z-index=5;">

<div id="SearchKeyBoard" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; top:0px; left:0px; z-index=6;">

  <div id="Brand_wrong" style="z-index:99; position:absolute; top:450px; left:200px; display: none; font-size:25px; font-family:'CenturyGothic'; width:1080; color:#000000;"><font face="NeutralText">* Brand not found. Please Enter a Valid Brand within the list</font>
  </div>
  <ul class="keyboard" id="Search_keyboard" style="z-index:8; position:absolute;left:230px; top: 1280px; color: #000000;">
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">0</span></li></font>

    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">q</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">w</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">e</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">r</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">t</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">y</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">u</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">i</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">o</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter lastitem">p</li></font>

    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">a</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">s</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">d</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">f</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">g</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">h</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">j</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">k</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">l</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter lastitem">z</li></font>

    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">x</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">c</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">v</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">b</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">n</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="letter">m</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">(</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol">< span class="off">)</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">@</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">-</span></li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="clear" style=" clear: left; width: 330px;">Clear</li></font>
    <font face="NeutralText"> <li class="delete lastitem" style="width: 349px;">Backspace</li></font>

    <font face="NeutralText"><li class="space lastitem">Space &nbsp;</li></font>
  </ul>
  <button class="Search" onclick="Search()"></button>
</div>
```

***Issue:***

I have created the following code but the issue that I am facing is:

2. When user keys in the character from the jQuery keyboard, it should always does a search on the following file name from the image array. And it should also always check if the input corresponds by eliminating image items that do not correspond to the input character. However,  the current behaviour that I am facing is that when user enters the characters, the `keyup` search function will only alternate a list of image item instead of eliminating incorrect images.
3. If the input has a correspond, an array of item image is displayed when only the relevant item image (only 1: correct item) should be displayed.
4. If none of the input of the correspond None of the image item is still be on display when it should return an empty image item list.

Correct behaviour of Search:

1. a list of image item is displayed, when user clicks on SearchField. The jQuery Keyboard is displayed
2. When user keys in the character from the jQuery keyboard, it does a search on the following file name from the image array.
3. If the input has a correspond, it will display the relevant item image (only 1: correct item).
4. Else,if none of the input of the correspond, it should return an empty image item list. None of the image should still be on display.

Hence, I would like to ask for help and to find out what has gone wrong.

Please help.